# how to read url hash params and how to get url hash (#) history within page in react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, url, hash, parameters

how to read the url hash params ?
how to track the history of hashes string?
how persist hash strings ?
how to scroll within the page on clicking on hash string?
how to validate url hash string?

I want to read hash string from id and also want to track the history of user who visits page and navigate between hashes